# useQuery wrapper querykey type mismatch

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query

A lot of queries in my project take the same params, it's a dashboard app. I'm trying to build a wrapper so I don't have to keep getting these params from my contexts.

The code I'm trying right now is

```
interface IUseLazyQuery {
  <
    TQueryFnData = unknown,
    TError = unknown,
    TData = TQueryFnData,
    TQueryKey extends QueryKey = QueryKey
  >(
    queryKey: TQueryKey,
    queryFn: QueryFunction<TQueryFnData, TQueryKey>,
    options?: Omit<
      UseQueryOptions<TQueryFnData, TError, TData, TQueryKey>,
      "queryKey" | "queryFn" | "initialData"
    > & {
      initialData?: () => undefined;
    }
  ): ReturnType<typeof useQuery<TData, TError>> & {
    fetch: Function;
  };
}

type IUseLazyQueryOptions<
  TQueryFnData = unknown,
  TError = unknown,
  TData = TQueryFnData,
  TQueryKey extends QueryKey = QueryKey
> = Omit<
  UseQueryOptions<TQueryFnData, TError, TData, TQueryKey>,
  "queryKey" | "queryFn" | "initialData"
> & {
  initialData?: () => undefined;
};

export const useLazyQuery: IUseLazyQuery = <
  TQueryKey extends QueryKey,
  TQueryFnData = unknown,
  TError = unknown,
  TData = TQueryFnData
>(
  queryKey: TQueryKey,
  queryFn: QueryFunction<TQueryFnData, TQueryKey>,
  options?: IUseLazyQueryOptions<TQueryFnData, TError, TData, TQueryKey>
) => {
  const [enabled, setEnabled] = useState(false);
  const resolveRef = useRef<(value: unknown) => void>();
  const query = useQuery(queryKey, queryFn, {
    ...options,
    enabled: enabled && (options?.enabled === undefined || options?.enabled),
    onSettled: () => {
      if (resolveRef.current) {
        resolveRef.current(null);
        resolveRef.current = undefined;
      }
    },
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setEnabled(false);
  }, [query.data]);
  return {
    fetch: () => {
      setEnabled(true);
      return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
        resolveRef.current = resolve;
        while (resolveRef.current) {
          await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 500));
        }
      });
    },
    ...query,
  };
};

export const useFilteredRequest = <
  TQueryFuncParams extends object,
  TQueryKey extends QueryKey = QueryKey,
  TQueryFnData = unknown,
  TError = unknown,
  TData = TQueryFnData
>(
  name: string,
  func: (params: TQueryFuncParams) => TQueryFnData,
  params: TQueryFuncParams,
  options: IUseLazyQueryOptions<TQueryFnData, TError, TData, TQueryKey>
) => {
  const { category, classification, selectedBrands } = usePageFilters();
  const { filterRequestParams } = useFilterContext();
  const { dataFinalStr, dataInicialStr } = useDateFilterContext();
  const filterParams = useMemo(() => {
    return {
      marcas: selectedBrands.join(","),
      classificacoes: classification,
      categorias: category,
      data_final: dataFinalStr,
      data_inicio: dataInicialStr,
      ...filterRequestParams,
    };
  }, [
    selectedBrands,
    classification,
    category,
    dataFinalStr,
    dataInicialStr,
    filterRequestParams,
  ]);
  const queryFuncParams = useMemo(() => {
    return { ...params, ...filterParams };
  }, [params, filterParams]);

  return useLazyQuery(
    [name, ...Object.values(queryFuncParams).sort()],
    () => func(queryFuncParams),
    options
  );
};
```

I'm getting a type error :

```
Argument of type '(string | null | undefined)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TQueryKey'.
  '(string | null | undefined)[]' is assignable to the constraint of type 'TQueryKey', but 'TQueryKey' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'readonly unknown[]'
```

on

```
return useLazyQuery(
    [name, ...Object.values(queryFuncParams).sort()],
    () => func(queryFuncParams),
    options
  );
```

`[name, ...Object.values(queryFuncParams).sort()]` is resolving to `(string | null | undefined)[]`
but somehow that conflicts with `readonly unknown[]`

Tried changing TQueryKey type around but nothing works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is why I always recommend to not build such low level abstractions over useQuery. The `useLazyQuery` wrapper is fine, for `useFilteredRequest`, you can't provide a generic of `TQueryKey` from the outside, because it could be arbitrarily instantiated. The function `useFilteredRequest` itself creates the QueryKey, so the type is relatively fixed, however, you still need to provide that type to the QueryOptions:

```
- options?: IUseLazyQueryOptions<TQueryFnData, TError, TData, TQueryKey>
+ options?: IUseLazyQueryOptions<TQueryFnData, TError, TData, (string | null | undefined)[]>
```

Here's a [working TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgRQK4FMoE8DS6sA0KG2AYqgHYDGMwEFRAqgM7pqZYDyYt9zRqVu2xwAvnABmUCCDgByAAIwAhhWYqqAawD0UdMpoBaAI4kscgFChIsRHEHoAyipjoBrAEroJ79AFl0EAhfAFEJCXQaMUlpWTk9AxhLKwpXKAkDdDgASRZ0ABllAC8sYSxECzg4AB5KqrgAFTLSCgARZRU4AF57Ck0KCAB3BjqqhpCoaShu3v6hkfrG9s6eprMW5eUCUcayvHL0AA9XCgATZmIOfZm9-DqAPgAKHdMr-AAuXbN97cXXsgon2alBodAo1TWHA2HS2XzeWHuv3qEB4YOYAH5PpwQMAYLVFlU8mVuLw1BDmm0YURxpNoNTNtTbgikYsAET-XD4VlwAA%20cHZ6wo3L5rOAFFxwGUABtNqydvc4AAyCoEuBiiXSzaYuCPACU3QVlFO3jF6FOAG4dqI6rrPl4YKgoBQGlgwOhqjBXegIBJ7EIzBCGY0JlN7grlQgdhEYFQABafcjUUmWqqiS3Wiyet05PKFErE1F8fFwgGbGaUObDJE0qblvoDKt1Bpl1YUhlNplwI4nc6XbDXHpMiwKnrY3HFolmElo8mCoM1ulLKklznMuoC%20HC-kclpb0Xi2iamFy8MqtUHyUymHavUG3rGiSmi0WNMWCxHGzwKh8eAOPOlMxPlyVh-zKGZi0hUsYTrSsFmDWlph6CsGzg5toNbOcqQ7b58C7Y50DOC5O0HHDCGHZ4qg5fZPkg1ckR3QE%20ywRNQXoWcoUpFRGVIxE6hRUkMSA3NigAjhpyLWjoS4%20CpnpZdaP2e4LH1LoFUjKpvzUeAAG0COUAAjKUzSIVgYBCCgDKM04AF1y1YZwOnQR4MilVhdRTOBNPUOA9GYCApQAN3QLxfSQzxvGqR4AulDBPmQ%20YVIVAKIGAU4nncuovPgDk7LYMxHnU%20oqPwFk4AYogdgAOmq-i0VKvTDLNT4GqspVlUeWq%20HRSqWrNbouiQs4TQoPqeT5Tq1G63rTl1Ur6EcdAYBgKzPlvVSz0WYBfUeXz-KCkLKqoR09FSfVCtVXbAuC7xDuOgiYEeChUClKUMtVKpLv2m6jsme66wfJ8PMWa1gaRUQMrqBwwgiGhHjWtSdlM8zLLNZzpTcjzRCIbSOUq04YWst6fMWx0KA2yRFrjVbEvJqokYsxrTkeGAoAwInFj0B0nTgEbBjgAAFWJgFYR5lGYLBqB1T70Bp86CWlg6fpO%20AemloGCUGWNgCMqX0D8q7Fbu07aYJZRBmUXEefQPnBZkYWnJ2vW9plu9TIaUBvVQB7paIABWAAGf3dXZgkQdDkOsaq6qOTB9NLXfQ5P08n8-XQUhtbSM0vFebyegg4FqH55QoGUEALm7AjewgfSACtIhgas23Q2YUOrENoBg1umxbFcpOUci6gskB0E%20dQoDFABzJEJBBVawGL0vmBoguqCLkuy5pyTOK2Op5-Xpfe5BNfF6RCaD%20AgoRILAT2Kg6SFygOTpMeMfJ95Hnnte7TrKU2XMpTx8Uo0jHzLrlAIQQ4Z-w5iTbmcsqggGLlQMWnxtJyGUHIIgch9JyGspVGuKUKCPFZAQVks0dgaSlGLZgW1gBIO-HrT4AADKglDmDUMfEg0kjDSoaUchPaAkoD5yE4egfh2AMHkLgPjFQAB9R8FkpSfDkNI5Q6cFHOCgBI1UKiZHqioHQT4T0XqlVfKmbGhMPJZTKusI%20C9QFhX8IECAkC7xy05qTOw1VKp7xPnALxgDgF2IuKYsQ2MfFlyIAEzAIDmAWLfBpFOmhcI9G0kPNwfjqqcFrvXSq0UpQYGYI8Hctj966msnUbQ2hFgAD10TxOJlzMmf4r75R2Eksiix4aSBBEUmxhcglkMWGfG0ccgA)